# How to use a generic class without the type argument in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, oop, generics, parametric-polymorphism

I want to encapsulate a *generic object* in another class *without* setting the generic type argument. I created a base `Animal<T>` class and defined other subclasses from it. Example:

```
public class Animal<T: YummyObject> {
    // Code
}

public class Dog: Animal<Bark> {
    // Code
}

public class Cat: Animal<Meow> {
    // Code
}
```

and defined an `Animal` property, *without* the type argument, in the `UITableView` extension bellow:

```
extension UITableView {
    private static var animal: Animal!

    func addAnimal(animal: Animal) {
        UITableView.animal = animal
    }
}
```

but I get the following compile error when doing so:

> Reference to generic type `Animal` requires arguments in `<...>`.

This seems to work fine in **Java**. How can I accomplish the same thing in **Swift** as well?

Comment: Can you please show us what is Meow and Bark. Is it a class, or a protocol. Also, what is the reason you want to assign a table to an animal and not some protocol. btw, Car doesn't go meow, it goes beeep beeep

Comment: @iWheelBuy It is a dummy object and a class

Comment: I would question whether this is a generic situation. Unless you show more info to the contrary, this looks like a use case for a protocol, not a generic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Swift doesn’t yet support [*wildcard-style generics*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) like Java does (i.e., `Animal<?>`). As such, a common pattern is to define a *type-erased* superclass, protocol (or wrapper) to enable such usage instead. For instance:

```
public class AnyAnimal {
    /* non-generic methods */
}
```

and then use it as your superclass:

```
public class Animal<T: YummyObject>: AnyAnimal {
    ...
}
```

Finally, use `AnyAnimal` in your non-generic code instead:

```
private static var animal: AnyAnimal!
```

**Examples in the Swift Standard Library**. For a practical example, see the [`KeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath), [`PartialKeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/partialkeypath), and [`AnyKeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anykeypath) classes hierarchy. They follow the same pattern I outlined above. The [Collections framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyhashable#see-also) provides even further type-erasing examples, but using *wrappers* instead.

Comment: Not applicable if the type you want to erase already extends another class and that class is a generic.