# Specify a generic value argument as a parameter of an object initialization call

Tags: swift, generics

I have a struct `Event` that gets initialized with a time and a value.

The `value` property's type is decided at the time the event is created. It can be one of either an `Int` or `Double` primitive.

How should I implement this in Swift?

I want to be able to create a new `Event` object like so:

```
let event = Event(time: Date.init(), value: EventValue<Double>(40.3467))
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498611/how-to-use-a-generic-class-without-the-type-argument-in-swift) but I can't make it out.

I have experimented with so many permutations of this and the best I can do is

```
struct Event {
  let time: Date
  var value: EventValue? // This line 'requires arguments in <...>'
}

struct EventValue <T> {
  let value: T?
}
```

Comment: I  wonder if a (non-generic) `enum EventValue { case ival(Int); case dval(Double) }` is what you are actually looking for ...

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thank you for the edits. That clears things up for me too ;)

Comment: @MartinR I am wondering what I am looking for as well. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to have a (single) `Event` type with an `EventValue` property which can hold *either* an integer *or* a double value, then an `enum` with associated values would serve that purpose:

```
enum EventValue {
    case ival(Int)
    case dval(Double)
}

struct Event {
    let time: Date
    let value: EventValue
}

let event1 = Event(time: Date(), value: .dval(40.3467))
let event2 = Event(time: Date(), value: .ival(1234))
```

Comment: This is the way I have it set up now. I think this is a good suggestion for a newbie to Swift. I was getting lost in the details of some of the language features (i.e. compiler flags EVERYwhere) that I don't necessarily have to understand yet. Happy to be moving forward with this.

Answer (score 4):

Add generic parameter to your `Event` struct too and then use this type for parameter of `EventValue`

```
struct Event<T> {
    let time: Date
    var value: EventValue<T>?
}
```

then just initialize `EventValue` without specifing type, since compiler allows you to pass just value corresponding to generic parameter constraint. And since your parameter has no constraints, it is equal to `Any`, so you can pass any type

```
let event = Event(time: Date.init(), value: EventValue(value: 40.3467))
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `EventValue` is generic, it can't be used directly as the type of a property.* You have to either directly specify the type parameter, which gives you a container that always has a particular variety of `EventValue`:

```
struct DoubleEvent {    // Please pick a better name, though
    let time: Date
    var value: EventValue<Double>?
}
```

Or make the container generic as well:

```
struct Event<T> {
    let time: Date
    var value: EventValue<T>?
}
```

In either case, you don't have to explicitly give the type when creating an `Event`: `let event = Event(time: Date(), value: EventValue(value: 40.3467))` Type inference will fill it in when the `Event` itself is generic.

(Aside: note that you have no formal restriction for `T` to be only `Double` or `Int`. For example, `let event = Event(time: Date(), value: EventValue(value: "123abc"))` is possible as well. If you do want to strictly avoid that, [Martin R's answer gives one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261258/).)

---

*Without getting into too much detail, it's more like a "thing that creates a type" than a type itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support various kinds of `EventValue` under the same `Event` type (i.e. no generics for `Event`), you can store a protocol reference for `EventValue`:

```
protocol EventValueProtocol {
    var time: Date { get }
    var value: SomeCommonGroundProtocolOrClass
}

struct Event {
    let time: Date

    // note that the generics information is lost
    // when using the protocol
    var value: EventValueProtocol

    init<T>(time: Date, value: EventValue<T>) {
        self.time = time
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct EventValue <T>: EventValueProtocol {
    let value: T?
}
```

The downside of the "type eraser" protocol is that you loose the type information used for the generic argument of `EventValue`, however it might be that you'll be able to work around this via some helper methods in the protocol. For example you can use a common denominator for all `T` generic arguments in order to access the common functionality (you kinda need this unless you want to switch over all possible types `T` can take).

Comment: I'm curious what types of helpers you would write in the protocol? If you care to share it might help me understand your suggestion better.